# How do I completely mock out a class with PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm reading this [documentation on PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) and it has two main examples:

1. Mocking static methods
2. Partially mocking a class

but I want to know how to mock an entire class that's created with `new`.  **I am looking for the PowerMockito version of Mockito's `mock` method**.  This should be able to replace `new Foo()` in my production code with a Mockito `mock(Foo.class)`, somehow.  Here's what I've tried:

```
import com.PowerMockitoProduction;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PowerMockitoProduction.class)
public class PowerMockitoTest {

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {

        HttpClient mock = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
        when(mock.executeMethod(any(HttpMethod.class))).thenThrow(UnsupportedOperationException.class);

        new PowerMockitoProduction().createClient();

    }
}
```

This test fails with this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException> but was<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>
```

Here's my production code:

```
package com;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;


public class PowerMockitoProduction {

    public void createClient() throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.executeMethod(null);
        System.out.println(client);
    }

}
```

With my debugger, I can see that the `client` is not a mock, like I expected.

I've also tried using:

```
Object mock = PowerMockito.whenNew(HttpClient.class).withNoArguments().getMock();
```

But for some reason, that returns a mock that is not completely constructed.  I've also tried this:

```
HttpClient mock = PowerMockito.whenNew(HttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock(HttpClient.class)).getMock();
```

But that gives me a `ClassCastException` on that line.  So, what is the correct way to mock out a class completely with PowerMockito?

Unlike this example implies, **the reason I'm trying to mock out HttpClient is so that I can call `verify` it later.**

Comment: What do you mean by mocking out a class completely. Sorry I went through your question a couple of times, but couldn't understand that part.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm looking for the PowerMockito version of Mockito's `mock` method.

Comment: You don't need to call `getMock()` method after `thenReturn()`.

Comment: @RohitJain ok well `thenReturn` does not return an `HttpClient`.  I want to `verify` on the mock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to call `getMock()` method to get back the mocked object. Basically, mock an instance of `HttpClient`, store it in local variable and use that:

```
@Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void test() {
    HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(HttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(httpClient);
    when(httpClient.executeMethod(any(HttpMethod.class))).thenThrow(UnsupportedOperationException.class);

    new PowerMockitoProduction().createClient();
    verify(httpClient).executeMethod(null);
}
```

Comment: Is this the way you're *supposed* to do it?  Seems a little convoluted.

Comment: Yes. You've to have mocked instance stored as local or instance variable, and use it around.